# Refreshing AWS temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

We use an authentication process for AWS whereby you authenticate, do an MFA step, and are then granted credentials that are valid for an hour. Usually these are then put in `~/.aws/credentials`. However, when doing long running awscli operations such as copying a large file via `aws s3 cp ...`, the credentials expire and the command does not complete successfully.

We have tried re-running the command to re-authenticate and thus repopulate `~/.aws/credentials` however the in-progress command does not "see" this and still fails when the original credentials expire.

How is this supposed to be handled?

Comment: If the answer below helped you solve your problem please upvote and accept it. That's the StackExchange way to thank the users for taking their time answering your questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a couple of options...

---

## Longer session duration

You can set the maximum session duration to **up to 12 hours** - that may be enough for your long running tasks.

[image: credentials validity]

Not sure how you're obtaining your temporary credentials, you may have to set the session duration there to 12 hours as well as some tools request tokens valid for to 1 hour by default.

Also check out [`get-credentials` script](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-utils/blob/master/get-credentials) that may facilitate your workflow. Maybe, I don't know what exactly are you doing now, however writing temporary creds to `~/.aws/credentials` is usually not the best practice.

---

## Copy to EC2 first

If you can’t increase the max duration setting you may be able to work around the limitation by:

1. first **copying** the data **to an EC2 instance**, e.g. using `rsync`.
2. then **from EC2 upload to S3**, taking advantage of the instance [**EC2 Instance Role**](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/) that automatically renews. Besides copying from EC2 to S3 *may* be faster.

---

## Use EC2 credentials locally

You can also "steal" the EC2 role credentials and use it locally. Check out this [`get-instance-credentials`](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-utils/blob/master/get-instance-credentials) script.

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-... ~] ./get-instance-credentials
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIA5G7...R3KG5"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="bzkNi/9YV...FDzzd0"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKf....PUtXw=="
```

These creds are usually **good for 6 hours**.

Now copy and past those lines to your local non-EC2 machine.

```sh
user@server ~ $ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASIA5G7...R3KG5"
user@server ~ $ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="bzkNi/9YV...FDzzd0"
user@server ~ $ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKf....PUtXw=="
```

And verify that the credentials work:

```sh
user@server ~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAIA...DNG:i-abcde123456",
    "Account": "987654321098",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::987654321098:assumed-role/EC2-Role/i-abcde123456"
}
```

As you can see you local non-EC2 server now has the same privileges as the EC2 instance from where you retrieved the credentials.

---

## Use `aws` CLI to *multipart-upload* the file

You can split your large file to smaller chunks (see [`split`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) man page) and use `aws s3api` multipart-upload sub-commands. See `aws s3api create-multipart-upload`, `complete-multipart-upload` and `part-upload`. You can refresh the credentials between each part and retry the failed parts if your credentials expire half-way through.

---

## Create a custom script

You can use the briliant [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) Python AWS SDK library to build your own file uploader. It should be very simple to write a little multipart-uploader that will request new credentials every time they expire, including asking for the MFA.

---

As you can see you've got many options.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: We do not have permission to change that duration - it is set that way as policy. I’ll look into the get-credentials script to see what that offers

Comment: @FredClausen ask your cloud ops team to increase the max time limit for you. Without that you can’t really get longer validity tokens.

Comment: They will not increase the timeout (we’ve asked) so I need to find a way to have the running client, awscli in this case, request fresh creds before the current ones expire.

Comment: @FredClausen updated the answer with a possible workaround. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions; I'll see if the EC2 approach is workable. I've also been thinking of splitting the large file into chunks that can be uploaded in an hour and then doing it piece by piece although that's tedious with manual cred renewal.

Comment: @FredClausen added few more options on how to tackle this problem. Hope some of it will help :)